# Sencha Touch 1.1 video not working in Android 4.0

Tags: video, sencha-touch, extjs

I have created a simple video panel with Sencha Touch 1.1 which works on iOS and upto Android 3.0 properly but not with Android 4.0. Is anyone else getting the same issue? I am using Android Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: You can try it on android simulator to see if this is merely the device issue - I have an issue with `window.openDatabase` is undefined in my NS ICS but running smoothly on the ICS on simulator

Comment: FYI: Sencha Touch 1 is not supported on Android 4 and there are numerous other bugs with it when running on 4. I highly suggest you make the switch to 2.x, if possible, as soon as you can.

Comment: @rdougan : Thanks a lot for the info. Can you provide me a reference where this fact that Sencha Touch 1.0 isn't supported by Android 4.0 is given??

Comment: @Swar I am on the development team for Sencha Touch. Android 4 was not out when Sencha Touch 1 was released and we no longer work on that version, so there obviously there are quite a few issues with it. :) We have spent a lot of time focusing on Android 2.x (>= 2.2) and 4.x (>= 4.0.3) performance for the 2.0 release, including many fixes for video and audio components. I highly suggest you upgrade to Sencha Touch 2 as it is now in RC, with a GA release just around the corner.

Comment: @rdougan Thank you for the info. I knew the issue you mentioned. Just I needed to confirm it from a source - because my client wanted a confirmation. Thanks, I will show him this post.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch 2 is now in [2.0.RC](http://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=90&a=28)

If you are developing a new app, look at upgrading to Sencha Touch 2, any bugs you find in Android can then be fixed before release of Sencha Touch 2